# Color clipping without using css

Tags: javascript, html

I have to do a simple lines clipping but I have to show both the lines that passes through the clipping region and also outside the clipping region using different colors, so the one within the clipping region will be red and the one outside will be blue. Is there away I can make this without using css? most of the tutorials I found uses css. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of Javascript to do this, although it's way too convoluted. Just use CSS3 as it's way easier and faster. You don't even have to create a specific CSS file to do this; just use the `<style>` tag.

Comment: Good answer, but I feel like it should be a comment instead, since it's concise enough and doesn't *exactly* solve OP's question, as they wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the style inside HTML

```
<div class="outside" style="background-color: blue; height:500px; width:500px">
        <div class="inside" style="background-color:red; height:250px; width:250px">
        </div>   
</div>
```